# Unidentified Method "Interests" - has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user that can create interest tags. Users have many interests and interests belong to users, very simple. I followed this (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide to set it up but i get the error: `undefined method interests for #<Interest:0x833e200>`

User model:

```
has_many :interests
```

Interest model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Database Migration:

```
def change
create_table :interests do |t|
  t.string :iVal
  t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

end

In my view:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.interests.build]) do |fi|%>
   <%= fi.label :interests %>
   <%= fi.text_field :interests %>
   <%= fi.submit%>
<% end %>
```

I've tried every solution i've found online but am yet to find anything that helps.

Any help will much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is for an interest object that belongs to the `@user`. Interests don't have `<%= fi.text_field :interests %>`

Interest, probably have a name, so a text field for the interest might be what you want in here instead:

`<%= fi.text_field :name %>`

Comment: Leito, you are correct. I cannot believe I overlooked something so simple. Thank you!

Comment: Aren't all mistakes simple once you know the answer? Happy to help, we've all make these mistakes more often that we would admit.

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests you're attempting to call `interests` from the `Interest` class, like so: `Interest.interests`.

If you're interested in using a form builder for a one-to-many relationship, consider reading this documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for